# Where do I hold the lighter to start the pilot light

Tags: furnace, pilot-light

Is it behind the black thing on top somewhere? All the videos say it's at the end of this tube but I don't see where.

[image]

Comment: you have not found it yet, take more photos

Comment: some systems have a push button to ignite, do you have one ?

Comment: the presence of the yellow cable indicates that you may have a piezo-electric igniter

Comment: What device (and make, and model number would be helpful) Range, furnace, water heater, fireplace... no way to tell from this picture. Either a thermocouple wire or an igniter wire. Kinda wonder if it's off to the right side where the holes in that shield are. It looks a bit sooty.

Comment: What do the instructions say?  They will instruct you on how to light the pilot.

Answer (score 2):

That looks nearly identical to the pilot assembly in my wall furnace. Here's a picture of it lit, so you can see where the flame goes:

[image: Pilot light shown through hole above the mounting point]

There is a hole in the sheet-metal several inches above, and that is where you should put your lighter. Mine takes many seconds after turning on the gas for it to get through the piping and be ignitable, so be patient, and you don't need to rush to get the lighter ready.

If you don't have a similar hole, I guess you'll have to stick the lighter up from below.

The tube on the left is the pilot burner, and the tube on the right is the thermopile or “generator” which converts heat from the pilot flame into electricity to operate the gas valve and thermostat circuit.

Comment: One of those lighters for lighting grills with the extension on them to get the flame away from you fingers is quite useful.